# the method will recurse infinitely

Tags: java, recursion

Given the following method declaration:

```
public static int fact(int num) {
    int tmp = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        tmp *= i;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

I want to write it again as a recursive method and then write a full program that take input from the user and find out fact (num).

I wrote this one but couldn't make it infinite:

```
public static int fact(int num) {
    int t = 1;
    int i = 0;
    if(i <= num) {
        t *= i;
    }
    return fact(t);
}
```

Comment: What do you think `t*=i` does if you've just set `i` to `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `num` does not get decremented at all and hence, it goes into infinite rerusion, calling the same `method` with same parameter values.

A simplified version would look like this:

```
public static int fact(int num) {
    if(num <= 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return num*fact(num-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A successful recursive function must progress towards the base case each time you run it.

With a factorial function, you have to subtract 1 from the parameter before it goes into the recursive call. (Why? Because `fact(5)` will use the result of `fact(4)`, which in turn will use the result of `fact(3)`.)

So, in the return statement, you'll be performing a calculation using your current parameter and the result of your recursive call - i.e. you'll be making the call `fact(num - 1)` and multiplying it by `num`.

Note that you won't need `i`, since the method parameter will take the role of a "counter" that just goes down with each call.

Example:

```
public static int fact(int num) {

    // Base case: 0! = 1
    if(num == 0) return 1;

    return num * fact(num - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static int fact(int num){
    //This is the ending condition
    if(num == 0 || num == 1){
        return 1; 
    }

    //Otherwise return num * fact(num - 1)
    return num * fact(num-1);
}
```

Example of how it works :

if you took `3` as input you will get:

```
3 * fact(3 - 1) = 3 * 2 * fact(2 - 1) = 3 * 2 * 1 = 6
```